# Rails 3 form_for :remote => true giving me a weird error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, rjs

I am getting the following error:

```
try {
Element.update("status", "This product doesn't exist.");
} catch (e) { alert('RJS error:\n\n' + e.toString()); alert('Element.update(\"status\", \"This product doesn\'t exist.\");'); throw e }
```

I'll just jump straight into it and give you my code:

view:

```
<%= form_tag '/product/verify', :remote => true do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<div id="status"></div>
```

products_controller.rb:

```
  def verify
    @product = Product.find_by_verification(params[:search])
    render :update do |page|
      if @product == nil
        page.replace_html "status", "This product doesn't exist."
      else
        page.replace_html "status", "This product is #{@product.status}"
      end
    end
  end
```

routes.rb

```
match 'verify', :to => "products#verify"
```

I have NO idea why this isn't working.  I have <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %> and <%= csrf_meta_tag %> in the header, i've tried the form_for with :method => :get

I do something almost exactly like this elsewhere in my application and it works perfectly (i'm using a select menu in that instance), but in that case it is actually modifying the database.  In this instance I am just looking something up.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was stupid of me.

It seems the problem was the route being the same name as the controller action? I changed the controller action name (and the path in the form_for) and it worked perfectly.

Argh!